# Kubernetes kubectl access environment variables

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Does anyone know why this one doesn't (shows empty line):

```
kubectl exec kube -- echo $KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST
```

but this one works?

```
kubectl exec kube -- sh -c 'echo $KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST'
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Running successfully will depend on the image that you are using for `kube`. But in general terms `echo` is a built-in [Bourne shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) command.

With this command:

```
$ kubectl exec kube -- echo $KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST
```

You are not instantiating a Bourne Shell environment and there is not an `echo` executable in the container. It turns out what `kubectl` does is basically running `echo $KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST` on your client! You can try running for example:

```
$ kubectl exec kube -- echo $PWD
```

You'll see that is the home directory on your client.

Whereas with this command:

```
$ kubectl exec kube -- sh -c 'echo $KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST'
```

There is a `sh` executable in your environment and that's Bourne Shell that understands the built-in `echo` command with the given Kubernetes environment in the default container of your Pod.

Answer (score 4):

One option that usually works without `sh -c`, in case it's needed, is:

```
kubectl exec kube -- env | grep KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason this shows an empty line has nothing to do with kubernetes or the container.  In your first line the `$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST` is interpreted by *the shell you're running in*.  And you must not have KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST set within that shell, so it uses an empty string instead.

Based on what you're seeing, I infer that you're trying to find out the value of the KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST variable *inside* your kubernetes container.  Your last command will do that for you, and I suspect the following one would do the same.

```
kubectl exec kube -- echo '$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST'
```

Comment: Btw, this command doesn't work. The accepted answer mentioned that `echo` will just be executed on the current shell. So this command will just display `$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST` in the current shell.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of the following command:

`kubectl exec kube -- echo $KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST`

The `$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST` expands from your local environment. The shell performs *parameter expansion* before executing the command. With parameter expansion, if we misspell the name of a variable or it is not defined, the expansion will still take place but will result in an empty string. The `KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST` is not defined on the local host so will result in an empty string. Essentially this is the command that will execute in the container:

`kubectl exec kube -- echo`

When we want to suppress all expansions, we use single quotes. So, in this case, the following command works because single quotes suppress parameter expansion, and the command is passed to the container unchanged.

`kubectl exec kube -- sh -c 'echo $KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST'`

Answer (score 0):

Generally, with the command:

`kubectl exec kube -- echo $KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST`

the `$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST` will be expanded first and supplied as an argument to echo. In your environment this variable might not be set, giving a blank line.

As for command:

`kubectl exec kube -- sh -c 'echo $KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST'`

a shell is created in your container and instructed (`-c`) to treat `'echo $KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST'` as a command string